# Mongoose Populate embedded ref field with aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have the following scenario, given that a customer can order different product in the same different. Example: Say on 12-02-2022 a customer came at 9am to order a product and same customer came at 2pm to order different product and at 3pm the same customer came to order different product; mind you all these purchases are on same date but we will have different customers purchases in the OrderDetails object Field of the Order collection.

******CUSTOMER

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const CustomerSchema = new Schema(
    {

CustomerName: {
  type: string
},
CustomerAddress: {
  type: string
},
CustomerEmail:{
  type: string
},
CustomerPhone:{
  type: string
}

},

toJSON: {virtuals: true, getters: true},
toObject: {virtuals: true}
})

const Customer = mongoose.model('Customer', SlotSchema);

    module.exports = Customer;

******PRODUCT

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ProductSchema = new Schema(
    {

ProductName: {
  type: string
},
ProductCode: {
  type: string
},
ProductCategory:{
  type: string
}

}, 

toJSON: {virtuals: true, getters: true},
toObject: {virtuals: true}
})

const Product = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);

    module.exports = Product


******ORDER

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const OrderSchema = new Schema(
    {

OrderNote: {
  type: string
},
OrderCode: {
  type: string
},
OrderDate:{
  type: Date
},
OrderDetails:{
  Customers:{
  type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: "Customer"
},
Products:{
  type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: "Product"
},
Quantity: {
  type: Number,
}, 
Amount:{
  type: Number
},
TotalAmount:{
  type: Number
},
}

toJSON: {virtuals: true, getters: true},
toObject: {virtuals: true}
})

const Order = mongoose.model('Order', OrderSchema);

    module.exports = Order
```

********My Expectation

I want to be able to do the following:

a)Find all Orders with Customer details(Customers collection) and Product details(Product collection) on a specific day. Where do I use the populate() method to find the details of each Customer and Product in the OrderDetails object field in the Order collection.

b)Sum the "Quantity" and "TotalAmount" field of OrderDetails object Field of Order collection from a specific customer on a specific date.

c) Can I populate all customer details and product details with aggregate without filtering(e.g searching by field name)  when i display all orders collection records?

*******My Efforts

```
const order = await Order
                    .findById({_id: req.params._id}).populate({ 
           path: 'customers', 
           model: Customer 
        },
          { 
           path: 'products', 
           model: Product 
        });                    

    /*GET TOTAL SLOTS THAT HAS BEEN ALLOTED FOR THIS SLOT*/                    
    await order.aggregate([ 
      { $match: {_id: {$e: req.params._id}}},     
      { $match: {OrderDate: {$e: req.params.orderDate}}},
      { $group: {
   OrderDate: null,   
   TotalQuantity: {$sum: '$Quantity'},
   TotalOrder: {$sum: '$TotalAmount'},              
 
 }, 
},
{$unset:["OrderDate"]},
    ], function(err, result){
        if(err)
        {
            return res.status(201).json({
    error: "Error retrieving your order."
        errorDetails: err.message
});
        }
    else{
      return res.status(200).json({
        status: 'success',
        order,
        totalQuantity: result[0],
        totalOrder: result[1],
    });
    }
})
```

The code is not producing any error and not displaying result and there are records in the database as well.

Thank you in advance